# How to quote array variable in SAS

Tags: arrays, string, sas

I have a dataset INPUT with a variable named color with couple of types:

```
obs  color
1     red
2     red
3     yellow
4     blue
...
```

Now I want to create flags for each types of the color:

```
DATA COLOR; SET INPUT;
ARRAY TYPES [3] RED YELLOW BLUE;
FOR I = 1 TO DIM(TYPES) DO; 
  IF COLOR = %unquote(%str(%')TYPES[I].%str(%')) THEN TYPE[I] = 1; 
  ELSE TYPE[I] = 0; 
END;
RUN;
```

So it not working well by using this way to added quotes for a array variable. Since I will need to create the same name of flag for each color type I thought I would be easier to write as Array. Please let me know if you know how to add quotes for array variables. So that I won't be need to write a many rows of IF STATEMENTS. When there are too many types of colors. Thanks.

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-dummy-variables-Categorical-Variables/ta-p/308484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays seem to be overkill for your example.  If you want to create binary variables then assign the results of a boolean expressions to the variables.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  red = color='red';
  blue = color='blue';
  yellow = color='yellow';
run;
```

For your ARRAY idea to work you will need to use the VNAME() function to find the NAME of the variable that corresponds to the array element.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array types red blue yellow ;
  do i=1 to dim(types);
    types(i)=upcase(color)=upcase(vname(types(i)));
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. but it runs much longer time than list all the IF loop. Do you know why?

Comment: The code with the DO loop and multiple function calls should be slower than the code that just compares the values since it is doing more operations.  Shouldn't really be much slower in clock time since most SAS code is I/O and not CPU bound.